# Cancel Notification with the buttons

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a notification made with `NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder` and it cancels fine when passing `.setAutoCancel(true);` to it, but I want it to cancel when also clicking on one of the given buttons with `.addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Ignore", pIntent2)` , currently it does not cancel, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To clear a particular Notification you can do it like,

```
notificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
```

Comment: so where exactly do I use this code, in the button of the notification or in the started activity?

Comment: You use this where you want to cancel your notification, so in this case, the button click.

Comment: the button's action is defined with ".addAction(R.drawable.ic_launcher, "Ignore", pIntent2)", which is passed a PendingIntent object, where again do I specify this cancel method in it?